# Laravel 5 Upload youtube thumbnail to server

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, youtube

I use Laravel 5.0 and Image Library (Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider).

So, I upload youtube thumbnail by url. I saw that Image Library uses file_get_contents and doesn't support https as you know. But I got solution then and just had replaced https with http and all was fine.

Today, I'm trying to get youtube thumbnail again but it failed. Laravel Logs said:

'Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException' with message 'Unable  to init from given url (http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZwsN2_YekI8/mqdefault.jpg).'

And my script shows 502 Error after 30 seconds for execution.

As I said it worked at least 3 weeks. I don't know why today is not working.

```
$url = $request->get('thumbnail');
$url = str_replace('https', "http", $url);
$filename = time() . '.jpg';
$path = public_path("images/" . $filename);
$image = Image::make($url);
$image->resize(300, 160);
$image = $image->save($path);
```

Is it possible to be server error? My hosting uses Nginx.